# Desenhar linha vertical centralizada em imagem

Tags: python-2.7, processamento-de-imagens

Estou trabalhando com processamento de imagens em Python utilizando a biblioteca PIL e Matplotlib e não estou tendo êxito no seguinte propósito:

Possuo a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de desenhar nela uma linha vertical e centralizada, conforme esse exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei diversas abordagens utilizando a biblioteca PIL, Matplotlib e tantos outros que encontrei, porém, não tive êxito.

Alguém sabe me dizer como faço isso?

Comment: Inclua o código em que mais se aproximou do resultado esperado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo utilizando **Pillow**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Desenhar linha em uma imagem.

Utilizando o Pillow:

.. code-block:

    pip install pillow

Os valores que devem ser passados para ``Line()``:

- valor inicial de x.
- valor inicial de y.
- valor final de x.
- valor final de y.

``fill`` é responsável por determinar a cor da linha:

- fill=(R, G, B, Opacidade)

``width`` determina a espessura da linha que será desenhada.

Após abrir a imagem:

.. code-block::

    img = Image.open('NomeDaImagem.jpg')

A variável ``img`` passa a ter algumas informações da imagem que foi aberta.
"""

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Abrindo a imagem.
img = Image.open('imagem.jpg')

# Colocando a imagem na área de 'desenho'
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# Desenhando a linha:
# Localizando o centro da imagem.
centro_x = img.size[0] / 2
centro_y = img.size[1] / 2

# Tamanho da imagem.
x = img.size[0]
y = img.size[1]

# Criando a linha.
draw.line((centro_x, 0, centro_x, y), fill=(255, 0, 0, 100), width=2)

# Descartando a área de desenho.
del draw

# Salvando a imagem com as modificações.
# img.save('imagem_com_linha.jpg', 'JPEG')
img.save('imagem_com_linha.png', 'PNG')
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vale notar que o centro da linha está utilizando como base o **tamanho** da imagem.

O tamanho da linha está indo de **zero** até o tamanho da imagem também, basta ajustas esses valores conforme as suas necessidades.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Renato Cruz!

Atende o que eu preciso.